# OpenCl in C, basic application causing access violation

Tags: c, opencl

I am trying to learn OpenCL, which is quite interesting but has a steep learning curve (at least for me).

Following the book: OpenCl in Action

I wrote a simple program that would provide me with information about the opencl devices i have, still no contexts, no kernels, no nothing.

I defined two structs (idea from some blog online):

**NOTE**: Please jump to the notice at the end of the file

**DeviceDesc**

```
typedef struct DeviceDesc{
    cl_device_id    deviceID;
    cl_device_type  Type;
    char*           TypeString;
    char*           Name;
    char*           Ext;
    cl_bool         Available;
    cl_ulong        GlobalMemSize;
    cl_ulong        LocalMemSize;
    cl_uint         Clock;
    cl_uint         ComputeUnits;

} DeviceDesc;
```

**PlatformDesc**

```
typedef struct PlatformDesc{
    cl_platform_id  pID;
    char*           pName;
    char*           pExt;
    char*           pVersion;
    char*           pVendor;

} PlatformDesc;
```

I also defined two enums

PINFO

```
enum pINFO{
    name = 0,
    vendor = 1,
    ext = 2,
    profile = 3,
    version = 4,


}pINFO;
```

DINFO

```
enum dINFO{
    dname = 0,   //char*
    davail = 1, //clbool
    dext = 2,  //char*
    dgmemsize = 3, //ulong
    dlmemsize = 4, //ulong
    dmaxclock = 5, //uint
    dcompunits = 6,//uint

}dINFO;
```

I also defined these *Functions*:

```
void cl_error_check(cl_int err,char* msg) {
    if (!err==CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("%s\n",msg);
        exit(1);
    }
}


void cl_PFINFO(PlatformDesc* platform,enum pINFO itype,int i) {
    size_t datasize;
    char*  data;
    cl_int err;

    //name = 0,   //char*
    //avail = 1, //clbool
    //ext = 2,  //char*
    //gmemsize = 3, //ulong
    //lmemsize = 4, //ulong
    //maxclock = 5, //uint
    //compunits = 6,//uint
    switch(itype) {
    case 0: //name
        err = clGetPlatformInfo(platform[i].pID,CL_PLATFORM_NAME,0,NULL,&datasize);
        cl_error_check(err,"Couldn't Obtain Plaform Name!");
        data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(datasize));
        clGetPlatformInfo(platform[i].pID,CL_PLATFORM_NAME,datasize,data,NULL);
        platform[i].pName = data;
        break;
    case 1: //avail
        err = clGetPlatformInfo(platform[i].pID,CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR,0,NULL,&datasize);
        cl_error_check(err,"Couldn't Obtain Plaform Vendor!");
        data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(datasize));
        clGetPlatformInfo(platform[i].pID,CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR,datasize,data,NULL);
        platform[i].pVendor = data;
        break;
    case 2: //ext
        err = clGetPlatformInfo(platform[i].pID,CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS,0,NULL,&datasize);
        cl_error_check(err,"Couldn't Obtain Plaform Extensions!");
        data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(datasize));
        clGetPlatformInfo(platform[i].pID,CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS,datasize,data,NULL);
        platform[i].pExt = data;
        break;
    case 3: //globalmemorysize

        break;
    case 4: //localmemorysize
        err = clGetPlatformInfo(platform[i].pID,CL_PLATFORM_VERSION,0,NULL,&datasize);
        cl_error_check(err,"Couldn't Obtain Plaform Version!");
        data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(datasize));
        clGetPlatformInfo(platform[i].pID,CL_PLATFORM_VERSION,datasize,data,NULL);
        platform[i].pVersion = data;
        break;

        break;
    default:
        printf("Unknown Platform Info Type! %d",itype);
        exit(1);
    }


}
void cl_DVINFO(DeviceDesc* dev,enum dINFO itype,int i) {
    size_t datasize;
    char*  data;
    cl_bool av;
    cl_int err;

    cl_ulong gm,lm;
    cl_uint  clock,units;
     //name = 0,   //char*
    //avail = 1, //clbool
    //ext = 2,  //char*
    //gmemsize = 3, //ulong
    //lmemsize = 4, //ulong
    //maxclock = 5, //uint
    //compunits = 6,//uint

    switch(itype) {
    case 0: //name
        err = clGetDeviceInfo(dev[i].deviceID,CL_DEVICE_NAME,0,NULL,&datasize);
        cl_error_check(err,"Couldn't Obtain Device Name!");
        data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(datasize));
        clGetDeviceInfo(dev[i].deviceID,CL_DEVICE_NAME,datasize,data,NULL);
        dev[i].Name = data;
        printf("\nDevice Name: %s",dev[i].Name);
        break;
    case 1: //avail
        err = clGetDeviceInfo(dev[i].deviceID,CL_DEVICE_AVAILABLE,sizeof(cl_bool),&av,NULL);
        cl_error_check(err,"Couldn't Obtain Device Availability!");
        dev[i].Available = av;
        printf("\nDevice Available: %d",dev[i].Available);
        break;
    case 2: //ext
        err = clGetDeviceInfo(dev[i].deviceID,CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS,0,NULL,&datasize);
        cl_error_check(err,"Couldn't Obtain Device Extensions!");
        data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(datasize));
        clGetDeviceInfo(dev[i].deviceID,CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS,datasize,data,NULL);
        dev[i].Ext = data;
        break;
    case 3: //globalmemorysize
        err = clGetDeviceInfo(dev[i].deviceID,CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE,sizeof(cl_ulong),&gm,NULL);
        cl_error_check(err,"Couldn't Obtain Device Global Memory Size!");
        dev[i].GlobalMemSize = gm;
        printf("\nDevice Global Memory Size: %lu",dev[i].GlobalMemSize);
        break;
    case 4: //localmemorysize
        err = clGetDeviceInfo(dev[i].deviceID,CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE,sizeof(cl_ulong),&lm,NULL);
        cl_error_check(err,"Couldn't Obtain Device Local Memory Size!");
        dev[i].LocalMemSize = lm;
        printf("\nDevice Local Memory Size: %lu",dev[i].LocalMemSize);
        break;
    case 5: //Max Clock
        err = clGetDeviceInfo(dev[i].deviceID,CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY,sizeof(cl_uint),&clock,NULL);
        cl_error_check(err,"Couldn't Obtain info on Device Max Clock Frequency!");
        dev[i].Clock = clock;
        printf("\nDevice Clock: %u",dev[i].Clock);
        break;
    case 6://Max Compte
        err = clGetDeviceInfo(dev[i].deviceID,CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS,sizeof(cl_uint),&units,NULL);
        cl_error_check(err,"Couldn't Obtain info on Device Max Computing Units!");
        dev[i].ComputeUnits = units;
        printf("\nDevice Compute Units: %u",dev[i].ComputeUnits);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Unknown Device Info Type! %d",itype);
        exit(1);
    }


}
```

I know this is a lot, but my program runs fine until i reach the part in the code marked with ==>
in the comments, 
the problem is sometimes, the code runs fine, other times in crashes after it identifies the 2nd GPU, 
here is the **main**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    /*
            OPEN CL INIT AND STUFF
    */
    cl_platform_id      platformID;
    cl_device_id        *CPUID,*GPUID;
    cl_uint             num_devices,addr_data,num_platforms = 1;
    cl_uint             num_CPU,num_GPU;
    cl_int              err, i;

    char                dname_data[48],dext_data[4096];
    int                 k;

    PlatformDesc*       platform = (PlatformDesc*)malloc(sizeof(PlatformDesc));
    DeviceDesc*         CPUS = NULL;
    DeviceDesc*         GPUS = NULL;


    err = clGetPlatformIDs(num_platforms,&platformID,NULL);
    cl_error_check(err,"Couldn't find any platforms!");
    platform[0].pID = platformID;
    //Get CPUs
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform[0].pID,CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU,NULL,NULL,&num_CPU);
    cl_error_check(err,"Error in finding CPUS!");

    CPUS = (DeviceDesc*)malloc(num_CPU*sizeof(DeviceDesc));
    CPUID = (cl_device_id*)malloc(num_CPU*sizeof(cl_device_id));

    err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform[0].pID,CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU,num_CPU,CPUID,NULL);\
    cl_error_check(err,"Error in Getting CPUS!");

    for (k = 0;k<num_CPU;k++) {
        CPUS[k].deviceID = CPUID[k];
        CPUS[k].Type = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU;
        CPUS[k].TypeString = "CPU";
        //get device info
        int l;
        for (l=0;l<7;l++)
        cl_DVINFO(CPUS,l,k);
    }
    //Get GPUs
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform[0].pID,CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,NULL,NULL,&num_GPU);
    cl_error_check(err,"Error in finding GPUS!");

    GPUS = (DeviceDesc*)malloc(num_GPU*sizeof(DeviceDesc));
    GPUID = (cl_device_id*)malloc(num_GPU*sizeof(cl_device_id));

    err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform[0].pID,CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,num_GPU,GPUID,NULL);\
    cl_error_check(err,"Error in Getting GPUS!");

    for (k = 0;k<num_GPU;k++) {
            //==> Most of the crashing occurs here... if they occur
        GPUS[k].deviceID = GPUID[k];
        GPUS[k].Type = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU;
        GPUS[k].TypeString = "GPU";
        int l;
        for (l=0;l<7;l++)
        cl_DVINFO(GPUS,l,k); //Here, i am getting the info "L" for the GPU K
    }

    //Ok Now get Platform info
    cl_PFINFO(platform,name,0);
    cl_PFINFO(platform,vendor,0);
    cl_PFINFO(platform,ext,0);
    cl_PFINFO(platform,version,0);
    scanf("%d",&k); //THIS SCANF is just to see if it reaches this part or not, useless
    //CLEANUP

    free(GPUID);
    free(CPUID);
    free(CPUS);
    free(GPUS);
    return 0;

}
```

Here is a sample output that i get from my machine

```
Device Name: AMD FX(tm)-8120 Eight-Core Processor
Device Available: 1
Device Global Memory Size: 2147483648
Device Local Memory Size: 32768
Device Clock: 4100
Device Compute Units: 8
Device Name: Tahiti
Device Available: 1
Device Global Memory Size: 2147483648
Device Local Memory Size: 32768
Device Clock: 950
Device Compute Units: 28
Device Name: Tahiti
Device Available: 1
Device Global Memory Size: 2147483648
Device Local Memory Size: 32768
Device Clock: 950
Device Compute Units: 28
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 2.206 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Sometimes the second tahiti isn't identified.
ANyways, i get a 0xC0000005 (which i think is access violation, aka has something to do with pointers)

My Question is, where did i go wrong :). i mean if i can't do this, how will i be able to handle the kernels :P

## **NOTICE**

due to requests, i will post the segment where the code fails:

**The Code Fails HERE**

```
for (k = 0;k<num_CPU;k++) {
    CPUS[k].deviceID = CPUID[k];
    CPUS[k].Type = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU;
    CPUS[k].TypeString = "CPU";
    //get device info
    int l;
    for (l=0;l<7;l++)
    cl_DVINFO(CPUS,l,k);
}
```

Comment: Where in the code do we start looking?

Comment: Can you make a minimal working example? (in fact, you may end up noticing the cause of the segfault that way)

Comment: Ok i will shorten the Code, and send you the part it goes south, thanks

Comment: You said the code crashes while looking for the second Tahiti GPU but you traced the SEGFAULT to the loop probing the CPUs? Are you sure about the location of the error? How did you track it? Try to flush I/O before you free everything, OpenCL SDKs are notoriously bad at cleaning up, the problem might not come directly from your code.

Comment: The loops in general that ask for info are what cause the crashes the CPU loop crashes sometimes (although not as likely as the tahiti) and even if all the loops worked, after the scanf ... just before the clean up, it crashes..

Comment: Plus, what do you suggest i do if i shouldn't use OpenCl's cleanups

Comment: Have you tried making your structs 16 byte aligned and padding them?  For example in Visual studio you put #pragma pack(16) before your struct and #pragma pack() at the end.

Comment: I just tried it, thanks for teaching me that.. but still didn't fix the problem.. i might even take a break from the problem until i can narrow down the main cause, debugging openCl is complicated